# Excel Crashes when workbook is opened

Tags: vba

I cannot figure out why my excel workbook file keeps on crashing everytime I open the file.

I have this event handler which I'm sure the one causing the problem.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    On Error Resume Next
    CurrEntities = Array("Curr1,Ent1", "Curr2,Ent2", "Curr3,Ent3")
End Sub
```

CurrEntities is declared as public in separate Module.

```
Public CurrEntities() As Variant
```

When I try to comment out the line - CurrEntities = Array("Curr1,Ent1", "Curr2,Ent2", "Curr3,Ent3"), the file can be opened without a problem.

So strange because it doesn't give any run time error, it will just prompt a message "Microsoft Excel has stopped working" and then the Excel closes.

Is there something I missed or violated an array variable declaration?

Comment: Do you have any other code, like an `Auto_Open()` sub? - even though you've declared the variable incorrectly and using the `On Error Resume Next` statement is very poor practice, these issues wouldn't necessarily cause an application crash.

Comment: There is no other code aside from this with event. If variable is declared incorrectly it should display run-time error but this one acts different, it causes the Excel to crash displaying "Microsoft Excel has stopped working".

Comment: I've put your code into a new Excel 2013 spreadsheet, and it opens without any errors. Can you try copying your code to a new spreadsheet to see if you still get the error?

Comment: @DeanOC, thank you, this problem is solved already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration above and the usage has no problem. I found out and rectified the problem when I tried to create another file and use only the necessary variable for testing. The problem was caused by another variable which is declared incorrectly:

```
Public CoCodes("00123", "00456", "00789") As String
```

I removed this line from my code and the above code worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public CurrEntities() As Variant
```

means: declare an array of Variant.

Replace with:

```
Public CurrEntities As Variant
```

and everything should be OK ;)

Unless... you want to use an array:

```
Public CurrEntities() As Variant

Sub Test()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim curent As Variant

CurrEntities = Array(Array("a", "b"), Array("c", "d"))

For i = LBound(CurrEntities()) To UBound(CurrEntities)
    curent = CurrEntities(i)
    Debug.Print "---=== " & i & " ===---"
    For j = LBound(curent) To UBound(curent)
        Debug.Print curent(j)
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Cheers,
Maciej

Comment: Yes I want to an array. Tried your example CurrEntities = Array(Array("a", "b"), Array("c", "d")) but the same problem.

Comment: I have another file same like this using public array variable but it was saved as lower version Excel 2003 and its working fine. This file I have now is saved as Excel 2012 because I need more number of rows and I cannot use Excel 2003 because of limited rows. Is this something to do with the problem?

Comment: @hymes, i have gor MS Office 2010 Pro and it works perfect! Why it doesn't want to work with Excel 2012 - i have no idea. To worlaround it you can create two dimensional array of string or dictionary or collection.

Comment: the problem has been solved. I tried to debug and use only the necessary variable for testing and it worked perfectly. I later found out that there is one variable which I declared incorrectly that is causing the problem. The only thing that is left questionable is why the Excel suddenly crashes. Anyway, I don't mind it anymore as the problem was solved already. Thank you for helping!